# Should freshly made egg-free lasagna sheets be dried before use?

Tags: pasta, lasagna

I've made lasagna sheets before, using eggs and semolina flour (one full egg to two yolks, and enough flour for a very dry dough). These sheets worked well, placed directly into the lasagna without cooking or drying.

Next, I tried to do this without the eggs, in the quest for a vegan lasagna. I replaced the eggs with water and made the dough to roughly the same consistency as before (which works fine for things like spaghetti).

Now, when I made the lasagna, the sheets came out unpleasantly mushy, with very little bite. There is a chance I overcooked the lasagna, or perhaps didn't knead it enough, but I wonder if maybe egg-free lasagna should be treated differently. Often, pasta made with eggs is dried first. I always assumed that's done because it can be dried (whereas egg-based paste goes bad), but perhaps it also alters the consistency, or stops it overcooking as quickly?

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to dry pasta (egg or water based) before cooking. That should not have impacted the texture issue.  Water based pastas are typically made with semolina and/or durum flours. The type of flour you used could definitely impact the texture. I would suspect it was not over cooking.  Most people actually undercook fresh pasta, not realizing it needs a bit more time than it seems...unless you really over did it.